# Google Apps Script Server Error Occurred clicking submit - occurs suddenly without script changes

Tags: google-apps-script

Our spreadsheet scripts have not changed in 3 months.  As of yesterday we get the error  "Error encountered: we're sorry a server error occurred Please wait a bit and try again"  when clicking the submit button on a particular function that has worked flawlessly for 3 months.  Nothing has changed, and this was verified by viewing the script revision history.  In addition, other functions are giving problems, like, "Cannot find function trim() in object...."  - again, this has always worked fine.

The only thing that has changed was that, for the documents in question, we had removed 1 user and readded a user (gmail address) yesterday morning and shortly after users began reporting this issue.  I don't believe I had ever removed a shared user before yesterday, by the way.

Is my only recourse to recreate the sheets???  Again, there have been no changes to this script and it worked flawlessly until I removed a user from sharing.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you still seeing this error, or was it temporary?

Comment: were there updates to your server software or settings?